# change image to another by clicking on it

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am currently creating a background image for my page. But i want to change the image to 3 more images by clicking on it.how do i do that?`
or
is there a way to set a floating images in the home page(NB: without clicking)

```html
<div id="background">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/74/af/5174af9036a59ec62dfccdb962ce7e90.jpg" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript and the DOM API. Here's one way to do it:

HTML:

```html
<div id="background">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/74/af/5174af9036a59ec62dfccdb962ce7e90.jpg" >
</div>
```

JS:

```js
const images = [
  "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/51/74/af/5174af9036a59ec62dfccdb962ce7e90.jpg",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646637758734-1adfd944ce4e",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646652690737-0d154e42e18d",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646652321379-ec8f6fc1c7b1"
];

const background = document.getElementById("background");
const img = background.querySelector("img");

let i = 1;
const changeImage = () => {
  img.src = images[i];
  i = (i + 1) % images.length;
};

// change image every 5 seconds
setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

This code sets up an array of images and selects the image element on the page. It then uses setInterval() to call changeImage() every 5 seconds. The changeImage() function sets the src attribute of the image to the next image in the array, and updates the index i to point to the next image. This creates a slideshow effect.

If you want to change the image on click, you can add an event listener to the image element, like so:

```js
img.addEventListener("click", changeImage);
```

Comment: its not working.actualy i was looking for a automatic slideshow of images

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?